# Windows Scheduled Task Does Not Work With Service Account

Tags: powershell, file-permissions, task-scheduler, service-accounts

I have an odd problem with a scheduled task.  The task is scheduled to run at 0202 every morning under a service account. The task is configured to run whether the user is logged on or not and the "Do not store password" box is not ticked.  The task calls a Powershell script to push files to an AWS S3 bucket.  Every morning, the task starts successfully but does not actually push the files.  I've tested the Powershell and that works when I run the script manually.

I added some logging using Start-Transcript and that tells me nothing.  The transcript file is created but only shows the script ran.  The Windows Security log shows an Audit Failure for the SeTcbPrivilege but, to my DBA's eye, the Windows Application and the Powershell logs show me that everything started successfully and nothing failed.

The part that really puzzles me is that when I change the schedule to run during working hours to test things, the task succeeds.  When I alter the schedule, I'm asked to enter the service account password and, once that's done, I log out of the instance completely.
After this, the necessary files are pushed out to the S3 bucket and the PowerShell transcript *shows* that the files have been pushed.  There is a significant difference in that, after the Audit Failure, there is an Audit Success for reading Credential Manager credentials for *my* admin account.  That suggests to me that at some point the Task Scheduler is running as me, which it shouldn't be.  What I don't understand is why, when I reset the schedule to run at 0202, the job does not work.  The instance seems to be in the same state as it was during the working hours testing, I'm asked to enter the service account password when I change the schedule and I'm logged out, but the files aren't copied.  Where could I be going wrong?

Comment: @GregAskew, because we never have done.  I've only got limited experience with Task Scheduler and storing passwords feels like a bad idea. Tell me otherwise and I'll go with it.

Comment: How do you run the script when you do it manually? With administrator privileges, you could try to enable that in the task https://www.thewindowsclub.com/how-to-run-scheduled-task-as-administrator-in-windows (almost similar in windows server)

Comment: I run the script through the PoSh ISE as Administrator so it stands to reason that running the task with the highest privileges would work better.  The strange part is why the task doesn't work in the early hours but does during the working day.  I've just tested it by altering the schedule and logging out and it's worked as expected.   I'll change the schedule to 0202 and see what state we're in tomorrow.